# How to play videos in pdf viewer in Angular?

Tags: angular, pdf-viewer

I am facing a problem while doing a project. I need to display some documents which are in .ppt. So I converted them to .pdf and used a pdf viewer to display them but there are some videos present in those ppts that can't be played in pdf.

So do u have any solution to solve this ? Please help me

```
  <pdf-viewer [src]="selectedItem.desp"
              [render-text]="true"
              [zoom]="0.85"
              [fit-to-page]="true"
              [show-all]="true"
              [page]="page"
              (after-load-complete)="afterLoadComplete($event)"
              style="display: block;"
  ></pdf-viewer>
```

Comment: Could you add a link to the pdf-viewer you are using in the question ? We'll need to know which tool is being used before we can address the problems in the tool

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-pdf-viewer

Answer (score 2):

I have gone through the PDf Viewer you used, as well as the original project it is based on. The viewer does not support displaying videos inside .pdf files. Nor do any other web based PDF Viewers.

Since the files you want to display are .ppt, I suggest you look into players that can display them directly, instead of converting them.

You can take a look at [WebViewer](https://www.pdftron.com/documentation/web/guides/full-api-overview/)

Comment: Oh ok. I did not have an in-depth look into it. there should be others available & it is also possible that a free viewer might not be available. That's a possibility you should be ready for.